# ES6 JavaScript async await not resolving

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

The following code was an attempt to rework the recursive solution I posted here: [How to do a Recursive ES6 Object Mutator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556433/how-to-do-a-recursive-es6-object-mutator).

This one is a simple match and replace, but has the same async dependency.

I have the following json input as a simple tester:

```json
[
  {
    "name" : "dexterity ability score increase by 1",
    "description" : "your dexterity score increases",
    "benefit": {
      "appliesTo": "$$$StatisticDef|(#name#:#dexterity#,#type#:#ability#)",
      "appliesWhen": "ongoing",
      "atLevel": 1,
      "category": "addition",
      "value": 1
    }
  }
  
]
```

Two things to note here:

1. the value for appliesTo. This is the string that I want to replace
   with a MongoDB fetched value (the async dependency).
2. The structure is an array of 1 value, this is to show that the input
   could have many values

I'm running this in the following mocha test, using sinon for mocking (this is not part of this query, it all seems to work, I'm just showing how this is being executed).

```js
describe('FeatureDefAdder suite', function () {

  var mock = sinon.mock(StatisticDef)
  

  test('should try again with the linear resolver', async function () {

    var queryObjJson = '{"name":"dexterity","type":"ability"}'
      mock
        .expects('findOne')
        .withArgs(JSON.parse(queryObjJson))
        .chain('select')
        .withArgs('_id')
        .chain('exec')
        .resolves('5dbff89209dee20b18091ec3')
    const data = JSON.parse(
      await readFile(
        new URL(
          '../../../../seeder/character/data/FeatureDef.json',
          import.meta.url
        )
      )
    )

    const result = await linearMongoObjectResolver(JSON.stringify(data))

    // returns data subbed by [object Promise]
    console.log('substituted: ' + result)

    const objectified = JSON.parse(result)
    console.log('objectified: ' + objectified)

    console.log('resval ' + objectified[0]['benefit']['appliesTo'])
  })
})
```

and now the matcher code:

```js
const linearMongoObjectResolver = async (data) => {
  // assume data is any json screed
  // need to find text that matches /"([\$]{3}.*#\))"/ signifying the DSL string /([\$]{3}.*#\))/
  // in each case, use the content to pull out the Mongo schema class and the query for the findOne call
  console.log(' input data: ' + data)
  var copyData = data

  // "$$$StatisticDef|(#name#:#dexterity#,#type#:#ability#)"
  copyData = await copyData.replace(/([\$]{3}.*#\))/, async (match) => {
    //console.log({ match })

    var parts = splitForeignKeyReference(match)
    var queryObjJson = jsonify(parts[1])

    console.log(
      ' mongoObj: ' +
        parts[0] +
        ' querydsl: ' +
        parts[1] +
        ' queryobjjson: ' +
        queryObjJson
    )

    // query obj = {name: 'dexterity', type: 'ability'}
    // console.log(' typeof query is object?: ' + typeof JSON.parse(queryObjJson))
    var subbedInstance = '""'
    console.log(' 1.subbedInstance: ' + subbedInstance)
    if (parts[0] === 'StatisticDef') {
      subbedInstance = await StatisticDef.findOne(
        JSON.parse(queryObjJson)
      ).select('_id')
    }
    console.log(' 2.subbedInstance: ' + subbedInstance)

    return subbedInstance
  })

  return copyData
}
```

and the (truncated) test output:

```bash
 input data: [{"name":"dexterity ability score increase by 1","description":"your dexterity score increases","benefit":{"appliesTo":"$$$StatisticDef|(#name#:#dexterity#,#type#:#ability#)","appliesWhen":"ongoing","atLevel":1,"category":"addition","value":1}}]
 mongoObj: StatisticDef querydsl: (#name#:#dexterity#,#type#:#ability#) queryobjjson: {"name":"dexterity","type":"ability"}
 1.subbedInstance: ""
substituted: [{"name":"dexterity ability score increase by 1","description":"your dexterity score increases","benefit":{"appliesTo":"[object Promise]","appliesWhen":"ongoing","atLevel":1,"category":"addition","value":1}}]
objectified: [object Object]
resval [object Promise]
 2.subbedInstance: 5dbff89209dee20b18091ec3
```

So despite the "subbedInstance" getting the value, after the Promise resolution, the "substituted" console output (at the test level) shows the unresolved "[object Promise]" for the "appliesTo" value.

So why does the awaited value remain unresolved? even though it actually is resolved?

Comment: If the `copyData.replace()` function is the normal string `.replace()` method, then that is NOT promise-aware and thus does not wait for your `async` callback to finish and does not use the promise it returns.  Thus, this structure cannot work.  To use async operations inside a callback, the caller of the callback must be async-aware.  Also, please understand that you cannot just stick a bunch of `await` statements in your code and expect them to do something useful.  `await` only does something useful when you're awaiting a promise that is directly connected to your async operation.

Comment: One way to solve a problem like this is to split this into three operations.  1) Find all the things you need to lookup in the database (put them all in an array), 2) Look them all up in the array and put the results all in an array or a Map, 3) Now that you have all the info from the database, run the `.replace()` operation and you don't have to do anything asynchronous because you already have the data from the database which you can directly return from the `.replace()` callback.

Comment: where do you got `readFile` from

Comment: @jfriend00 - but the caller is async aware, it calls .replace on a object of type String inside a test that is itself async and the call to linearMongoObjectResolver is `await`ed, so I don't think I tried to "just stick a bunch of await statements in [my] code and expect them to do something useful". I expected them to await the resolution of the promises, like to doco says it should

Comment: @jfriend00 - as to your second comment, you misunderstand what I'm trying to do. The whole point of this exercise is that I have some items in a database for which i need the ids, but I don't know which ones i need ahead of time. I need to go through the json input and discover them. Now I could just find out what I need to fetch, sure, but, really, that's a pretty messy workaround for something that's supposed to work.

Comment: @bill.gates -  `readFile` probably comes from fsevents, which is from Node.js - I'm using 16.15.0

Comment: I understand completely what you're trying to do and made a suggestion for how to solve the problem.  Yes, you need to go through the JSON input, get all the ids you will need into an array, then go get all the data from the database, then you can use `.replace()` with the data you previously retrieved.  You cannot use an asynchronous callback in `.replace()` so your current approach will never work.   The replacerFunction callback you pass to `.replace()` has to be synchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 - i see, thanks. In fact, there's an npm package that addresses this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-async

Comment: @MichaelCoxon - It looks like that NPM module may fit your needs then.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I've just tested it - it works, thanks again

Comment: It's worth looking at how the `replace-async` works [here](https://github.com/dsblv/string-replace-async/blob/main/index.js).  It does something similar to what I suggested.  It calls `string.replace()` once, calls your async replacer function on those and collects all the promises from your async replacer function.  Then, it uses `Promise.all()` to wait for all your async replacer functions to finish.  Then, it calls `.replace()` again, this time using the results from the resolved array from `Promise.all()`.